# Please Explain meaning of {} syntax for me

Tags: php, variables, syntax, curly-braces

I am a newbie and try to learn PHP especially INSERT INTO statement. I'm know that if we insert value for String we must use '' syntax. But i don't understand meaning of {} syntax for "title" and"link". Any guys can explain for me. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You're looking at a templated string.  A string enclosed in double quotes in PHP can be written this way.  `$varName = 'hello'; echo "varName is {$varname}\n";` will output `varName is hello`.  The item between `{}` is a variable whose value is used. @mickmackusa says it's poor practice because it's ripe for a SQL injection attack. He's correct for this context, but the general practice of templated strings is NOT bad.

Comment: Do NOT use that query, it is insecure.  Research mysqli prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: Please include your code as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

On Sql side there is no difference between '$title' or '{$title}' . but in php {$title} is a more complete syntax of $title, that allows one to use :

- `"this is post {$title}s"`
- `"{$object->data}"`
- `"{$array['data']}"`
- `"{$array['data']->obj->plop['test']}"`

The curly braces "escape" the PHP variable and are not passed to MySQL. With a simple variable like $title it doesn't make a difference but with something like $post['title'] it does. for more information [check this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)